# Find a vector $\mathbf x$ whose image under $T$ is $b$.

Tags: matrices, transformation

I am having trouble with this question and how to get the answer.

With $T$ defined by $T(\mathbf x)=A\mathbf x$, find a vector $x$ whose image under $T$ is $b$.

$$
A =  \begin{pmatrix}
1 & -3 & 2  \\ 
3 & -8 & 8  \\
0 & 1 & 2  \\
1 & 0 & 8
\end{pmatrix} \qquad,\qquad
b = \begin{pmatrix} 
1  \\
6  \\
3  \\
10
\end{pmatrix}
$$

What I have done so far is that I've combined the two matrices into a augmented matrix. And row reduced it to get:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -3 & 2 & 1 \\  
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\  
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
So does this just mean that the answer to the question is $\mathbf x = \begin{pmatrix} 
1  \\ 3  \\ 0  \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $??

Comment: Welcome to math.SE, Sofia! I've edited your post in order to make it more readable. Please, visit the [help page](http://math.stackexchange.com/help), to learn how this site works and also how to typeset your question with $\LaTeX$! =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you now have to do is solve the system of equations
$$x_1-3x_2+2x_3=1$$
$$x_2+2x_3=3$$

What happens when you solve for $x_2$ in the second equation?  Hint: (use a parameter, like let $x_3=t$)

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1: If $A$ has $3$ columns, the dimension of $x$ must be $3$.

Hint 2: To check your result, compute $Ax$ and see if you got $b$.